# 32 bit depth jpg images problem in IE when referenced locally

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jpeg, bpp

We have an webbapplication that takes an image that will be uploaded and resized.
The resize-library we used saved all pictures with 32-bit depth whatever the depth was before.

We have an online client that can view the pictures via an html-file and all is fine there. All pictures are shown correctly.

**The problem:**
We also have an vb-winform application that download the pictures and show them in an html-file locally in an webbrowser control. But here all pictures are rejected (not rendered), just the red cross. If we create an static html-file with img-tags in them locally, its the same. All pictures that has 32-bits depth are shown as red crosses.

If we resave the pictures with 24-bits depth it magically works again. So ofcourse that was our "workaround", let the resize-library save all pictures with 24-bits depth instead.

**Summary:**
32-bits jpg files shows correct in IE when online but not when referenced locally in a local html-file. (This is true for IE8 on both winxp and windows7). The same local html-file opened in mozilla showed OK.

**Question:**
I have googled this a lot but has not found anything about this "problem". Is this a bug in IE8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem with my own webapplication.

This isn't only a problem from IE8 but a lot of other browsers can't support the 32 bit depth on a jpg file.

For the while, no solution exist. Try to convert your picture in a 24 bit depth. Or wait for IE9.0 that comes soon. It's the only way you have.

Comment: Its funny though, that it only affects images browsed locally, but not files browsed from web.

Comment: Added this as the accepted answer as it Confirms that it IS a problem in IE.

Comment: I know this is an old post, just in case someone come here. I have same problem on internet explorer 11 and still not working, saved image as 24 bit depth and done. works fine now.