# FreeASPUpload: Uploading Large BitDepth Images don't show in IE

Tags: asp-classic

I am using [FreeASPUpload](http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/documentation.asp) and got the script working... uploading all types of images (bit depth of 24) properly, until i uploaded this large hi-res 32 Bit depth .jpg file and it didn't show up in IE, but does show in FF.  I am assuming it's a Charset issue, but freeASPupload uses utf-8, which is common i believe for this.  Does anyone know what the issue may be that is causing these images being uploaded to not show up in IE and how to fix it?

Comment: How high of a resolution are we talkin'? And is it simply not showing up in IE but the upload was successful, or did the upload fail?

Comment: upload is successful, in FF it shows up, in IE it shows as a broken image.  The problem i think is the Bit depth, which is 32, instead of 24, the other images were showing fine which were 24 bit depth.

Comment: Just found and looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553942/32-bit-depth-jpg-images-problem-in-ie-when-referenced-locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i guess it is an issue with the app, it's an issue with internet explorer. And they show up fine remotely (not locally).  This is resolved thanks to the info from a fellow member from another question:

> 32-bits jpg files shows correct in IE when online but not when referenced locally in a local html-file. (This is true for IE8 on both winxp and windows7). The same local html-file opened in mozilla showed OK.

[32 bit depth jpg images problem in IE when referenced locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553942/32-bit-depth-jpg-images-problem-in-ie-when-referenced-locally)